# Does http post to "https" url's body is encrpyted in HTTP dart flutter package or in general? Don't know how to ask this qus, see below for brief

Tags: node.js, http, flutter, dart, https

*Sorry for the above improper question, Here's the brief of the question:*

"I have built the restapi for the app, in node.js, and I am sending and receiving data using http.post method to the https server using below code, does the body of the **POST** method is encrypted and safe from attackers?"

Sample code:

```
http.post("https://www.bsnlfskfncilif.com/jefnj/nnj", body: JsonEncode({
    "something":"something",
       "something":"something"
  }),
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
  );
```

Above code snippet reference: https://pub.dev/packages/http

**P.S: If there is something wrong with question, suggest edit , I am open for ideas.**
*Thanks for the help in advance :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your http request does use the https protocol if that is your question. So it has all the security of the SSL Certificate.

Comment: Thanks alot, benedikt, So, it's hard to read the json data from the outside.? , and is it required to add some kind of  encoding like , `encoding: Encoding.something('utf-8');`

Comment: You should just test if your API calls work with the encoding. I would assume it works fine. Sending passwords etc over https is standard practice, so I dont think you have to worry about your security there. Your Data gets encoded by the protocol.